# Python 3 booleans

Tags: python-3.x

So, for below I got: `return century == year // 100 + 1 or century == year / 100`

However, I'm not satisfying the last one:

```
>>>in_century(2013, 20)
False
```

How do I make it so that it is only True if the century is exactly equal to year divided by 100?
Also, is the format of the expression more or less correct?

Thank you!

Here is the question:

```
def in_century(year, century):
    '''(int, int) -> bool

    Return True iff year is in century.

    Remember, for example, that 1900 is the last year of the 19th century,
    not the beginning of the 20th.

    year will be at least 1.

    >>> in_century(1994, 20)
    True
    >>> in_century(1900, 19)
    True
    >>> in_century(2013, 20)
    False
    '''
```

Comment: (year - 1) // 100 + 1

Answer (score 1):

So, your code is this?

```
def in_century(year, century):
    return century == year // 100 + 1 or century == year / 100
```

You probably don't want an `or` here.

```
>>> in_century(2000, 20)
True
>>> in_century(2000, 21)
True
```

Try calculating the century for a year directly, and then comparing.

```
def century_from_year(year):
    return (year - 1) // 100 + 1

def in_century(year, century):
    return century_from_year(year) == century
```